# What to consider to choose in Magento 2.0.x and 2.1.x?

Tags: magento2, comparison

What are the technical points that I need to consider to choose Magento 2.0.14 or Magento 2.1.6? (Or any 2.0.x comparing to 2.1.x)

Seems like the both are the last versions available and we haven't some CLI commands and params on 2.0 versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless there is some reason compelling you to stay on 2.0 (for a site already running 2.0.x), you should always go with the latest release of the latest branch (2.1.7 at time of writing). 2.0 is still being maintained for security (rather than Magento releasing patches like they did for M1), but that's about all.

If you're creating a fresh install, again go with the latest (2.1.7).

PHP requirements do differ somewhat. 2.0 requires PHP 5.5 to 7.0. 2.1 requires PHP 5.6 to 7.0 (dropping 5.5). And while Magento 2.2 is not yet released, it's expected to require PHP 7.0 to 7.1 (dropping 5.6). That being said, this shouldn't be a reason to avoid upgrading: [all PHP 5.5 support ended in July 2016, and 5.6 active support ended January 2017](http://php.net/supported-versions.php).

There aren't any major functional differences between the two that would push you toward using the older version over the new one. 2.1 is more stable than 2.0.